# Need button on product detail page shopify app development

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I am new to shopify app development i have created an app using php using this tutorial
https://github.com/phpish/shopify_app-skeleton

I have created an app backend on admin side successfully, now I am stuck in a point where I need to add button on product detail page which will open a popup on that page,

When we install the app the button should appear on the product page

I don't know I can really explain my problem or not; any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your App can load a Script Tag that fires at the online_store. The script code you execute would then have to figure out if it is running on a product details page, at which point it could pop-up a modal for you if you decide it is. Nice thing is this code disappears from the shop when the merchant uninstalls the App, so it is a clean approach.

Comment: can you please explain how you add a script tag i am getting this error
Warning: Closure::call() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given
Or can you refer some tutorial from where i can get help , i am stuck in this point. thanks

Comment: @david-lazar "script code you execute would then have to figure out if it is running on a product details page" => could you please ellaborate on how to do that ? Also, this javascript would probably need to add container to an identified container: How to make sure such a container get populated to the store product page ?

Comment: @numair since this was 2 years ago, you probably solved this somehow: please answer your own question for future reference.